# Html.AntiForgeryToken with only IIdentity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif

I have a custom identity which implements IIdentity, but it does not inherit from ClaimsIdentity.  In the past, you could have a custom Identity that worked fine as long as it implemented IIdentity.

I have gotten my ClaimsAuthenticationManager working to map an external SSO process onto my custom identity.  Since each provider could present a different set of claims, I use the ClaimsAuthenticationManager to map them onto discrete properties where appropriate.  Providers do not provide any permissions.  All permissions are managed in the application database.  I.e., I am only leveraging external authentication, but authorization is managed through my own database.

The problem is it seems like AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier requires that my custom identity inherit from ClaimsIdentity.  I do not see any interface that ClaimsIdentity inherits from other than IIdentity.  This means my only option as far as I can tell is to inherit from ClaimsIdentity, and along with it inherit alot of other methods/properties I do not have any interest in exposing in my custom identity.  Just to support

In other words, when using an identity like this:

```
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public int SomeCustomProperty { get;set;}
    public List<CustomPermissions> Permissions {get;set;}
}
```

I get an error of:

> A claim of type
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
>   or
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider'
>   was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery
>   token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the
>   configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the
>   ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims
>   provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier,
>   it can be configured by setting the static property
>   AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.

To further demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish, this is mapping the claims based authentication onto my CustomIdentity(non claims identity):

```
public class KentorAuthenticationManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity;

        // create our custom identity
        var customIdentity = new CustomIdentity();
        customIdentity.IsAuthenticated = claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated;
        customIdentity.AuthenticationType = claimsIdentity.AuthenticationType;
        customIdentity.Name = claimsIdentity.Name;

        // ...if IsAuthenticated, use SAML NameId to 
        //        find user with matching AuthenticationUserExternalId in our database
        // ...initialize CustomIdentity.Permissions from database

        GenericPrincipal newPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(customIdentity, null);          
        return newPrincipal;

    }

}
```

The authentication works perfectly fine with this approach.  It doesn't seem like AntiForgeryTokens should depend on a concrete ClaimsIdentity implementation.  That seems ridiculous to force me to use such a heavy identity.

**Is there a way to use `Html.AntiForgeryToken` without having a `ClaimsIdentity` (while using a claims based identity provider only for the *initial* authentication)?**